is there a way to Bulk Convert Lead?
I think the possible solution for this would be a LWC Component to bulk convert leads into contacts linked to one account and optionally opportunity.
is this possible by flow or apex?

You can refer to this: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJdWcUAL

I will check this app in my dev org. Thanks.

It is possible to do this using a flow and apex together. However, it may be easier to use a free app from the app exchange, such as this app
If you still want to do this with flows and apex, you can try the following:
Use a screen flow that calls an apex class.
Create an apex class to convert leads:
Apex Class:
    public with sharing class LeadConversionUtility {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void convertLeads(List<Id> leadIds) {
        List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
        
        for (Id leadId : leadIds) {
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
            lc.setLeadId(leadId);
            lc.setConvertedStatus('Qualified'); // Make sure the status exists in your org
            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true); // Change to false if you want to create an Opportunity
            leadConverts.add(lc);
        }

        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> results = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
        for (Database.LeadConvertResult result : results) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                System.debug('Error converting lead: ' + result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

Screen flow:

Screen Element: Create a screen where users can select a list of leads.
Get Records Element: Fetch the selected leads.
Loop Element: Loop through the collection of selected leads.
Apex Action Element: Call the Apex class you created, passing in the current lead ID from the loop.
End Loop: End the loop.

